# Installing Windows Phone SDK for VS 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Windows 7, and have installed VS 2012 professional.  Previously I installed the Windows Phone 7 sdk.  Worked fine in VS2010.

When I try creating a WP7 project in VS 2012 I don't see the option.  I tried downloading and reinstalling the WP7 SDK but am getting prompted to repair/reinstall the existing installation, which must mean it's already on there?   Is there a trick I'm missing to getting a WP project type to appear in VS 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2012 only supports Windows Phone 8 SDK.

You can build Windows Phone 7.1 app using Windows Phone 8 SDK on top of VS 2012.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-windows-phone-sdk-8-0.aspx

Comment: The WP 8 SDK says I have to be running Windows 8 to install it.  Can that be right?  I can't develop windows phone apps using VS 2012 unless I'm running Windows 8?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have to have Windows 8 to have VS 2012 and Windows Phone 8 SDK. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/11/02/windows-phone-8-sdk-requirements.aspx

Comment: I find it irritating that I have to upgrade to an OS I don't want or use an outdated IDE if I want to develop for WP. I thought Microsoft was trying to _encourage_ WP development.